# Discrete Math: Induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

Given a non-zero integer $x$, prove by induction that $x^2$ is a factor of $(x+1)^n-nx-1$ for all integers $n \ge 2$.

Can anyone guide me on how to write the predicate and the induction step for this question?

Edit: Can I write the $P(n)$ as $(x+1)^n -nx -1 \bmod x^2 = 0$?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would formulate the predicate as
$$(x+1)^n - nx - 1 \equiv 0 \pmod{x^2}$$
which is equivalent to
$$(x+1)^n \equiv nx+1 \pmod{x^2}.$$
Now what happens if you multiply by a factor of $(x+1)$ on both sides?

Comment: I multiplied on both side and could get $$(x+1)^(n+1)$$ on LHS and on RHS its just (nx + 1)(x+1)

Comment: Multiply the RHS out and use the rules of modular arithmetic.

Comment: Oh right! I think i got it thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just for verification, this is the clearest proof.

\begin{align}
& (x+1)^n-nx-1=\left( \sum_{i=0}^{n} {n\choose i} \cdot x^i \right) -{n\choose1}\cdot x^1 - {n\choose0} \cdot x^0 = \sum_{i=2}^{n} {n\choose i} \cdot x^i \\
& = x^2 \left( \sum_{i=2}^{n} {n\choose i} \cdot x^{i-2} \right). \blacksquare
\end{align}

Now, this is the proof by induction.

\begin{align}
n=1: \; & x+1-x-1=0. \\
n=k: \; & x^2 | (x+1)^k-kx-1. \\
n=k+1: \; & (x+1)^{k+1}-(k+1)x-1\equiv(x+1)(kx+1)-(kx+1)-x \\
& \equiv kx^2 \equiv 0 \pmod {x^2}. \blacksquare
\end{align}

Comment: Was the question requirement, so i had no other choice but to do it by that way :(

Comment: @drago Alright, then I'll edit my post.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation